# Откуда берется namespace OpenPop.Mime.Message?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, namespace

Адаптируя код из чудого проекта, я столкнулся с таким неймспейсом: `OpenPop.Mime.Message` в участке кода, грубо говоря

```
        SmtpMessage smtpMessage = new SmtpMessage();
        var t = new OpenPop.Mime.Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(smtpMessage.RawMessage), true);
```

При этом я получаю сообщение

```
    Error   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OpenPop' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

я поискал, но не вижу какого то очевидного пространства имен или модуля, которые нужно подключить. `System.Net` и `System.Net.Mail` - уже подключены.

Я использую NET Core, но точно та же ситуация при попытке использоваь более старый Net Framework.

Подскажите, что нужно подключить к проекту, чтобы этот OpenPop.Mime.Message стал доступен?

Спасибо.

Comment: А искать пробовали? Не уж то проще задать незнакомым людям вопрос и ждать пару часов, пока поищут за вас, чем самостоятельно взять и вбить в любую поисковую систему `OpenPop.Mime.Message`, которая даст вам сразу первым же запросом ссылку на проект [OpenPop.NET](https://github.com/foens/hpop), где и будет этот ваш [OpenPop.Mime.Message](https://github.com/foens/hpop/blob/master/OpenPop/Mime/Message.cs). Также, если у вас есть исходники чужого проекта, то и там наверно тоже можно глянуть что за библиотеки подключены? Короче, не понять мне вас...

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал искать, я просто не мог поверить, что "ноги" у этого немспейса растут из внешнего проекта, а не из какой то хитрой NET-овской же DLL-ки